# Событийная система.

Tags: события, алгоритм, проектирование, шаблоны-проектирования

Доброго времени суток. Возникла очень непростая задача, а именно - создание событийной модели.

Фишка в чем:

1. Есть пользователи, группы пользователей
2. События, которые могут создать эти пользователи для круга других пользователей.

Если взять аналог - возьмем ВКонтакте: 
Человек написал на стене в какой-нибудь группе какое-то сообщение - уведомление об этом могут получить все пользователи к которые относятся к этой группе.

Казалось бы - ничего сложного, если, конечно, не учесть тот момент, что подобных событий протекает миллиарды штук в минимальное кол-во времени.

Отсюда встал вопрос - как бы Вы реализовали алгоритм отрабатывания таковой событийной системы ?

Как сейчас утроен проект ( минимально ):

1. Любой объект (группа пользователей, пользователь, и т.д.) - это объект, имеющий свою битовую маску по которой я определяю его тип.
2. Событие - объект, который имеет битовую маску его типа (тип события) и id сущности (п.1) к которому оно относится.

Когда создается новое событие - осуществляется новая запись в БД и при выборке тому, кого оповестить я серчу соседнюю таблицу и ищу все сущности, к которым оно относится.

Что не удобно:

Чтобы не оповещать 10 раз сущность - мне приходится сначала ее найти, а потом записать время последнего сбора ивентов в поле => 2 итерации (чтение, апдейт). Неудобно.
Подписка на основные группы событий может в себя включать до 10.000.000 записей ~ 20.000.000 итераций. Согласитесь - кошмар.

Так же, каждое событие должно храниться не более 5 минут. Если его сущность не получила в течении этого времени - фик с ней :)

Как будут появляться идеи - буду их выписывать сюда.

Заранее - спасибо за помощь :)

Comment: Рекомендую [посмотреть вики][1]


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Comment: - Мне кажется, что отправка сообщения в случае потенциально большого их количества не должна триггерить нотификацию всех `subscriber`. Максимум, что она может делать - это помечать, что, скажем, для такого-то пользователя есть новые сообщения.

- Дальше этот самый пользователь уже может отправить запрос с семантикой "выдай мне все новые сообщения для меня".

Comment: @Станислав Комар, Вы пишете

1. Подписка на основные группы событий может в себя включать до 10.000.000 записей

2. каждое событие должно храниться не более 5 минут

В своем ответе, (как мне показалось) Вы склоняетесь к предложению @Котик\_хочет\_кушать работать по опросу со стороны подписчиков.

Поподробнее о системе, пожалуйста. Сколько запросов в секунду (видимо по сети?) Вы предполагаете обслуживать?

Comment: @avp "работать по опросу со стороны подписчиков" - верно. Если подписчик онлайн, он каждые 3 секунды кидает запрос на получение новостей.

Пример {"evt":{"fl":7}}

например, есть ивенты типа : 

main: 1, 
message: 2,
addsub: 4

в объекте evt я даю указаель на получение всех типов событий (опционально).

В ответ я получаю { 1: {}, 2: {}, 4: {} };

ивент должны получить не все, а только те, кто успел в ближайшие 5 минут ! => кто был в сети, тот и получил, кого не было - тот не получил. Думаю, в среднем, одновременно запросов будет валиться не меньше 100.000.В данном деле волнует стабильность БД

Comment: Одновременно 100.000 - это установленных TCP соединений? 

На каких технических средствах (сетевое оборудование, компьютеры, ОС, система хранения) Вы собираетесь эксплуатировать эту систему?

--

А для начала хотя бы проверьте, сколько сокетов позволяет открыть Ваша система разработки. Можно даже не по сети.

Comment: Это меня меньше всего беспокоит. Меня больше беспокоит оптимальная структура хренения всего этого и оптимизация получения нужных ивентов :) 

Меня никоим образом не волнует сколько я могу принять одновременных подключений (поверьте, то, на чем это будет крутиться дает возможность для подключения хоть всего Китая одновременно). Если переходить на личности, то - Амазон и один из Голландских хостинг-провайдеров и один Русский. Так что, не переживаю я за это ;)

Comment: @Станислав Комар, очень жаль...

Comment: @avp обратите внимание на мой вопрос. Хотя, я уже выбрал алгоритм. Шустренький достаточно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно, пришел к 2-м выводам:

1 Есть сущность, которая делает запрос на получение ивентов по битовой маске.
  . Сущность знает какие сущности к ней относятся и серчит БД с ивентами по ID сущности и битовой маске (чтобы получить только те ивенты, которые мне нужно получить), которая их создала. Получили объект(не важно, пустой или полный), записали время последнего запроса.

==  Стек == 
 1. Есть таблица ивентов. У ивентов есть ID с его описанием.
 2. Есть сущность с контейнером ссылок на ивенты. Когда создается ивент, ивентная сущность вносит в стек всех подписанных на нее сущностей ссылку на необходимый ивент и при заборе ивента ссылка очищается. Так же, чистится база ивентов => ссылка может указывать на несуществующий объект (не принципиально).

Собственно, вот 2 способа. Есть предложения еще  ?

P.S. Презде чем пичать - попробуйте прочитать, собственно, то, что я хочу, и дать адекватный ответ, а не перекидывать ссылки на вики с описанием паттернов проектирования :)

Answer (score 0):

Наверное тебе нужен RabbitMQ, или что-то подобное.